# Expand width from Left side css

Tags: html, css

I have created an animation where i am expanding before element in key frame like this,

```
.expertise_item:hover::before{
    opacity:1;
    -webkit-animation:widthanimationexperties 3s cubic-bezier(0, 0, 0.72, 0.79);
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count: 1;
}
@-webkit-keyframes widthanimationexperties {
    0% { max-width:0;}
    50% { max-width:150px; }
    100% { max-width:300px;}
}
```

I have even odd situation and i have flip the even.

```
.expertise_item:nth-child(even)::before{
    bottom: -33px;
    left: -134px;
    -moz-transform: scaleX(-1);
    -o-transform: scaleX(-1);
    -webkit-transform: scaleX(-1);
    transform: scaleX(-1);
    filter: FlipH;
    -ms-filter: "FlipH";
}
```

Q. How i expand div from left side instead of right for even elevemnt.

Comment: Where is your `HTML`?

Comment: HTML doesn't matter its just  a div

Answer (score 0):

You can expend html element in css put

```
margin-left: -134px;
```

Comment: I have to expand div from 0 to 300px; but from right to left

Comment: give it a width and height like width: 300px; height: 300px; and also give a background: #000;  this will make you a div of 300 square. And the purpose of background will show your div with black color.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can use `animation` to make a growing effect from the left side

[See the fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9aa5pmz2/)